# как настроить звук в блютуз наушниках

Tags: linux, bluetooth, manjaro

на ноутбуке второй системой стоит manjaro, в интернет захожу через hrome. когда включаю видео на ютубе, иногда звук  может чередоваться меджу наушниками(т.е буквально каждую секунду включается сначала в одном ухе потом во втором потом снова в первом и тд)

Answer (score 0):

Положи оба наушника в контейнер. Нажми кнопку спаривания. Удали наушники в линукс и добавь заново. Если в поиске появятся 2 варианта подключения - попробуй оба.